# react submit form then redirect issue

Tags: reactjs, forms, redirect, post, form-submit

I have a form that must serve 2 tasks after submission:

1. send the form data to the server
2. redirect to another page

I'm having difficulties making both things happen;
The first one is easily accomplished using `<Form action='/blabla'>`, but then I get a blank page with the returned information from the server side as text.
The second one is also easily accomplished using `<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>` with the function:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch('/blabla', {method: 'POST'})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        history.push('/nextPage')
    })
    .catch(error => {
        alert(error)
    })
}
```

And it works fine, except no data is sent from the form to the server :(

So, can someone explain me please how to get both tasks above done?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be more clear if you can post the  as well.
Anyway, only from the snippet I say your fetch doesnot have `body` field in configuration, like:

```
    fetch('/blabla', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' // or 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data), // adjust this according to Content-Type header
    })
```

that might be the reason why there was no data sent to server.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I've used FormData and useRef to deliver the data to the fetch-body and it works just fine :)